# performance on parse date format [javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, date, d3.js

I'm using these 3 lines to recode dates from text to some d3 format (to use afterwards with crossfilter & dc.js).

I'm using the D3 functions to do this, but these 3 lines are slowing down my javascript
(~1000ms each when data is 10k records long).

I'm looking for faster alternatives in pure JavaScript or jQuery.
(I would prefer to avoid other plugins since performance is at stake, but any answer is welcome)

Thanks!

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"); // ISO 2014-12-16
var inputFormatDate = d3.time.format("%d %b %Y"); // 16 Dec 2014

data.forEach(function (d, i) { 
    // (...)
    d.Released = inputFormatDate.parse(d.Released);
    d.DVD = inputFormatDate.parse(d.DVD); // e.g. Tue Dec 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
    d.release_date = formatDate.parse(d.release_date);
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: What about stupid simple `new Date('2014-12-16')`?

Comment: i prepared a small test: http://jsperf.com/parse-date-d3-vs-pure

Comment: It might be as simple as that. I'm testing and the différence I see is that empty dates return null before and Invalid date now.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is pretty slow vs. optimal parsing in pretty much every date library, unfortunately. My recommendation: if you know the format the date will be coming in, then get the relevant attributes using `String.substr` and then use the `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]])` format of the Date constructor to build your Date object. In my experiments this should parse in about 20% of the time of the d3.js parser.

Comment: can month be 'Nov' or need it to be 11 ?

Comment: It would need to be 11. So you'd want to create a dictionary (outside of your parse function scope) and use it for the Nov -> 11 lookup.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, for `RFC3339 (%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)`, which is used in golang by default, you can use

```
function parseDate(d) {
    // 2015-05-13T04:01:01Z
    return new Date(d.substr(0, 19));
}
```

to replace

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse;
```

The first one using `new Date()` runs **significantly** faster than d3's function.

Here are more formats supported natively in JavaScript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp